# Doctrine, MVC, Symfony: where may I use Doctrine? May I use it in controller?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Lets see my architect:

Model:

```
// links table: (ID, LINKNAME)
Class Link extends Link_base
{
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->links = new Doctrine - here I build the query, SELECT, ORDER BY, etc
}
```

in this example, the model can be remain empty (no serious logic), all I need is a select with an order by. Im not sure I can use Doctrine in controller though - should I remake it like this?

```
Class Link extends Link_base
{
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return new Doctrine - here I build the query, SELECT, ORDER BY, etc;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->links = Links::getLinks();
}
```

Im not sure which way seems to be OK. Of course, when selecting needs a more complex, formatting todo-s, it goes to the model or helper - but I feel like I just made a new (unnecessary) layer. This getLinks() used only once. In other words: Doctrine may be only used in model, or can it be used in controllers too?

Comment: May - yes; should - **NO**

Comment: could you confirm that with an example, or a source?

Comment: Doctrine2 is a persistence abstraction framework (implementing [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern) and should never be exposed to the persistence layer. Instead it should be utilized in services for storing and retrieving data from domain objects (within model layer).

Answer (score 2):

Your entities (or models if you prefer that name) should **not** know *how* they are saved to / retrieved from the database. They should just be simple PHP objects, only containing a number of properties (corresponding to the database columns) and their getters and setters.

(If you are interested, read a bit about the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) which states that every class should have one, and only one responsibility. If you make your entities both responsible for storing data **and** knowing how to save that data in the database, you will have a greater chance of introducing bugs when one of those things changes.)

You can fetch entities from inside your controller:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LinkController extends Controller
{
    public function fooAction()
    {
        $links = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('YourBundle:Link')
            ->findAll();

        // do something with the result, like passing it to a template
    }
}
```

However, you might need a more complex query (that includes sorting and filtering) and you might need to run that query from multiple controllers. In that case, you don't want to duplicate that logic to multiple controllers, you want to keep that logic in one central place.

To do so, create a repository:

```
<?php

namespace Your\Bundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class LinkRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT l FROM YourBundle:Link l ORDER BY l.name ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

And add the repository class to your mapping:

```
Your\Bundle\Entity\Link:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Your\Bundle\Repository\LinkRepository
```

(check the [Symfony's documentation about custom repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) if you're using XML or annotations instead of Yaml)

Now in your controller, you can simply update your `fooAction` method so it uses your custom repository method:

```
public function fooAction()
{
    $links = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('YourBundle:Link')
        ->findAllOrderedByName();
}
```

For more information, Symfony's documentation includes a [great article about Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html). If you haven't done so already, I'd definately recommend reading it.

Comment: Nicely explained. This reminds the usefulness of repositories.